# Why do I get 'could not resolve "registry.giantswarm.io"' errors from boot2docker?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, giant-swarm

When trying to push an image to a private docker registry, I get this error every now and then:

```
FATA[0080] Error: issecure: could not resolve "registry.giantswarm.io":
lookup registry.giantswarm.io on 213.168.112.60:53: no answer from server
```

I'm using boot2docker on a MacBook.

Answer (score 3):

While the root cause is not completely clear to me, this seems to be related to switching networks and thus changing DNS settings. Probably the virtual machine used by boot2docker doesn't pick up the changes.

**Prior to boot2docker version 1.7**

Restarting the boot2docker VM usually helps:

```
boot2docker down && boot2docker up
```

**boot2docker version >=1.7**

With newer boot2docker versions, restarting the VM isn't enough in practice. This additional command helps in many cases:

```
boot2docker ssh 'sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart'
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to:

ensure you have

`https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/releases >= v1.7.1 installed`

and

`boot2docker down && boot2docker up`

and last but not least

`boot2docker ssh 'sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart'`

install, restart boot2docker, and reboot the docker service running on the boot2docker vm..